# How to actively duplicate Facebook group to another group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I'm a member of Facebook Group 1, and I would like to duplicate (archive) all the posts (including videos, units, images) to another group automatically as and when new posts are given.

Is there an easy way to do it?